# How to mitigate replay attacks for ASP.Net application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We use Oauth2 authentication with Okta for our Classic ASP.Net MVC website.  After the user logs out of the application, he can "replay" an old request with all of the original cookies and still get access to the website.  How can I prevent this security hole?

I have successfully developed a custom ITicketStore for my ASP.Net Core websites to solve this problem (similar to https://ml-software.ch/posts/implementing-a-custom-iticketstore-for-asp-net-core-identity), but I cannot find a similar concept to ITicketStore for Classic ASP.Net applications.

Comment: What do you mean with logout? Actually logging out, or closing a screen?

Comment: @klekmek, I am using IOwinContext.Authentication.SignOut to log out.  After which, I can continue to access secured parts of the application, if I had previously captured the authentication cookie and re-use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is an equivalent to ITicketStore in Owin, which is called IAuthenticationSessionStore.  You can find an example at: https://rhastastudio.wordpress.com/2016/07/19/owin-authentication-and-session-store/